# Validar campo solo letras y espacios con Request Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, validación

Estoy que hago validaciones los input text y tengo un input que se llama 'nombre' donde quiero que solo entren letras ya sean minusculas, mayusculas, espacios, con tilde o sin tilde y la letra 'ñÑ', pero nada de numeros. Este es mi codigo:

MyRequest

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'departamento'=>'required|integer|not_in:0',
            'nombre'=>'required|regex:([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s]+)'
        ];
    }
```

Esta todo bien pero hay problema y es que si pongo por ejemplo "Nombre1", me cuenta normal cuando tendria que decirme que el campo no es válido, ese es mi problema. Necesito ayuda por favor :s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDICIÓN:

Para validar letras **y espacios**, se debe usar un regex o crear una regla personalizada:

```
'nombre' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
```

Si deseas crear la regla personalizada, puedes revisar la documentación de Laravel.

---

Para validar SOLO letras, existe la regla alpha:

```
'nombre' => 'required|alpha',
```

Más información en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-alpha

---

Este es su código fuente:

```
/**
 * Validate that an attribute contains only alphabetic characters.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateAlpha($attribute, $value)
{
    return is_string($value) && preg_match('/^[\pL\pM]+$/u', $value);
}
```

Comment: si pongo 2 textos me sale error con 'alpha'

Comment: Entonces no es solo letras lo que quieres validar, eso es lo que dice el título.

Comment: en donde escribo mi caso pido tambien que tenga espaciado :s

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvio! ^^